# How to select an individual cell using ListView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have created a small app, for which View part is as below.
I have used ListView for showing my data. This table (ListView) is being updated once I enter the data and click on Save. After which if I click on the data, the whole row is selected.
But I am not sure how to click an individual cell.
Can I do it using ListView? If Yes how? Or I need some other component?

**VehicalForm.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Seris.VehicalForm"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="600">
<WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10 " >
    <Label Content="Vehical No" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <TextBox Name="VehicalNo_Text" Height="23" Width="80" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding VehicalNo}"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    <Label Content="Model" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <TextBox Name="Model_Text" Height="23" Width="80" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding Model}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
    <Label Content="Manufacturing Date" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <DatePicker Name="ManufacturingDate_DateTime" SelectedDate="{Binding ManufacturingDate, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <Label Content="IU No" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <TextBox Height="23" Width="80" Name="IUNO_Text" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding IUNo}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <Label Content="Personnel" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    <ComboBox Name="Personnel_Combo" Text="{Binding Personnel}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="116"/>
    <Separator Height="20" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Width="16"/>
    <Button Name="Save_Button" Command="{Binding SaveButton_Command}" Content="Save" Width="66"/>
    <Label x:Name="Error_Label" Content="{Binding ErrorMessage, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="41" Width="137"/>
    <ListView Height="294" Width="371" ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Vehical No" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding VehicalNo}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Model" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Model}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="ManufacturingDate" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ManufacturingDate}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="IUNo" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IUNo}" />
                <GridViewColumn Header="Personnel" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Personnel}" />
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</WrapPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: `DataGrid` can solve this problem easily or you have other option to create a property for selection state and manipulate the same upon mouse down of the particular item and reflect the same via data templates

Comment: pushraj: May I know how it works?

Comment: with DataGrid you can set `SelectionUnit` property to `Cell`. with ListView it may required adjusting the templates and some code. so do you want to remove the row selection and have only cell selection?

Comment: @pushpraj: So do I need to replace GridView with DataGrid?

Comment: you may need to replace ListView with datagrid

Comment: @pushpraj: Then DataGrid.View is not accessible. Can you please provide me edited code?

Comment: here is a nice tutorial on [datagrid in wpf](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/datagrid-in-wpf/)

Comment: I am unable. Can I do the same using ListView?

Comment: @pushpraj: Anyways Its done. Thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this with a DataGrid. Replace your listview with something like this;

```
        <DataGrid Height="294" Width="371" ItemsSource="{Binding ListItems, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionUnit="Cell" SelectionMode="Single" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Vehical No" Binding="{Binding VehicalNo}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Model" Binding="{Binding Model}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ManufacturingDate" Binding="{Binding ManufacturingDate}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="IUNo" Binding="{Binding IUNo}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Personnel" Binding="{Binding Personnel}" />
    </DataGrid>
```

Two important properties of the DataGrid are;

```
 SelectionUnit="Cell" SelectionMode="Single"
```

These allow you to control how a user can select items. In this example you can only select a single cell.